# Access to output from steps executed with matrix strategy in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am running a GitHub Actions job with `matrix` strategy, more or less as follows

```
      - name: ${{ matrix.users }}-${{ matrix.comment-type }}
        id: ${{ matrix.users }}-${{ matrix.comment-type }}
        shell: bash
        run: |
          COMMENT_DATE=(something that depends on matrix users)
          echo "::set-output name=${{ matrix.users }}-${{ matrix.comment-type }}::$COMMENT_DATE"

      - name: echo issue and pr comment dates
        shell: bash
        run: | 
          echo "Last ISSUE comment date: ${{ steps.${{ matrix.users }}-${{ matrix.comment-type }}.outputs.${{ matrix.users }}-${{ matrix.comment-type }} }}"
```

In the second `step` of the `job` I am trying to access these outputs but the following syntax is not working

```
${{ steps.${{ matrix.users }}-${{ matrix.comment-type }}.outputs.${{ matrix.users }}-${{ matrix.comment-type }} }}"
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are those 2 steps both part of the matrix steps? If so - I don't think you really need to have a dynamic "id" - just use a fixed one

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25634

Comment: Any luck with this @pkaramol? Seems this is an unresolved issue across the GitHub community forum too

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/29333#discussioncomment-3389347) to be useful